# Changing Hangfire storage type on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

I have an Asp.Net Web API project that uses Hangfire. Here you can see its registration in Startup.cs --> ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseMemoryStorage());
services.AddHangfireServer();
```

It is working fine, but I have to make it possible to change the storage type to PostgreSQL in the runtime. Is there any way to achieve it?

I am using dotnet 5

Comment: In .net framework, we added a package `Hangfire.PostgreSql`. When initializing we first create a `PostgreSqlStorageOptions` object (so we can set `PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = false`, because I don't want my application db user to be able to change database schema, so we prepared it earlier), and then `UseStorage (new PostgreSqlStorage(connectionString, psOptions)` - that'd probably be in place of your `.UseMemoryStorage()`  - Yours will be slightly different in .net 5 but it's a direction to start in.

Comment: @GregHNZ thanks for the response. Learning PrepareSchemaIfNecessary really helped